# how initialize variable in GetX controller?

Tags: android, flutter, initialization, future, flutter-getx

I have `GetxController` with the late Map data and I won't fill this in `onInit()` after searching on the database, but when the page is open the emulator shows the red screen with the not initialize error.
I need the `dataMap1` and 2 for showing the `PieChart` when the screen opens.
I think this occurred because I use the `Future` function, But I do not know how to fix this.
this is my entire controller code.

```
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:hive/hive.dart';

class ReportScreenController extends GetxController{

   late Map<String, double> dataMap1;

  final Map<String, double> dataMap2 = {
    "ورزشی": 5,
    "خصوصی": 3,
    "اداری": 5,
    "دسته بندی نشده": 3,
  };

  @override
  Future<void> onInit() async {
    super.onInit();
    //categoryScrollController.position.ensureVisible()
    await reportFunction();
  }

  Future<void> reportFunction() async {
    //dataMap1
    var taskBox = await Hive.openBox('task');
    var taskFinish =
    taskBox.values.where((task) => task.status == true).toList();

    var taskUnFinish =
    taskBox.values.where((task) => task.status == false).toList();
    double test = double.parse(taskFinish.length.toString());
    double test2 = double.parse(taskUnFinish.length.toString());
    print(test.toString());
    print(test2.toString());
    dataMap1.addAll({
      'رو زمین مانده': test2,
      'تکمیل شده': test,
    });
  }
}
```

my view code is

```
class ReportScreen extends GetView<ReportScreenController> {
  const ReportScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        fit: StackFit.expand,
        children: [
          background(),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15.0),
            child: Column(
              children: [
                const Text(':نمودار فعالیت', style: boldText),
                MyPieChart(dataMap: controller.dataMap1),
                const Text(':نمودار وظایف', style: boldText),
                MyPieChart(dataMap: controller.dataMap2),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to initialize `dataMap1`, simply in `onInit()` add dataMap1 = {}.
I think you also dont need a `late` modifier, just use final `final Map<String, double> dataMap1 = {};`, but everybody is choosing thier weapons.

In addition i think there will be problem with that how you use `controller.dataMap1` in your view. Most likely you dont rebuild your view after you finally initialize / populate `dataMap1`.

Update:

You can change in controller:
`late Map<String, double> dataMap1;` to `final RxMap<String, double> dataMap1 = RxMap();`, and in your view:

`MyPieChart(dataMap: controller.dataMap1),` to `Obx(() => MyPieChart(dataMap: controller.dataMap1.value))`

Comment: so how to rebuild my view after initialize datamap1? i add my view code now

Comment: thank you. now is everything is fine and worked.